# Does Emacs have elm-lang programming language support?

Tags: emacs, elm

I am getting started with Elm language https://elm-lang.org/ and I am using Emacs but did not find any package/plugin for elm-lang. 
In case if you know any then please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found one. `elm-mode` https://github.com/jcollard/elm-mode
I got reference from this site  from https://riptutorial.com/elm
which has plugins mentioned for other other editor/IDE too.

Comment: It's worth noting that while *elm-mode* is a wonderful package that provides the core functionality to use Elm in Emacs, Emacs distributions such as Doom or Spacemacs have the advantage that they also come with other pre-configured functionalities like on-the-fly syntax checking for Elm.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to try using [Language Server Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) for elm. It help to bring the most up-to-date solution for any editor, including Emacs.

1. Install [elm-language-server](https://github.com/elm-tooling/elm-language-server) on your machine.
2. Install [lsp-mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode) package in your Emacs and configure some settings.

---

If you are **Doom** of **Spacemacs** user, you can use one of the preconfigured solutions.

- For **Doom** use preinstalled [elm](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/tree/develop/modules/lang/elm) module
- For **Spacemacs** use [elm](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/elm) layer

Comment: To enable language server in Emacs Doom, you can find the industrctions here. https://github.com/elm-tooling/elm-language-server#emacs-doom